# Laravel 5, get the HTTP status code from Blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I'm using custom error views with blade files located in `resources/views/errors`. My error views are made from the same template view than the normal pages so they extend my `frontoffice` layout. Here is the hierarchical scheme of my templates.

```
app.blade.php
    layout.frontoffice.blade.php
        someFrontOfficePage.blade.php
        404.blade.php
```

The navbar component is included in `layout.frontoffice.blade.php` so I can't access it from `404.blade.php`. Just to be clear, the navbar is a [component as described here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#components-and-slots) and is thus in yet another file.

**The problem:** I want to hide the links in the navbar but not the navbar itself when in an error view (such as `404.blade.php`). The idea was to check if the status code is different from 200 inside my navbar component but I don't know how to access the response from a blade file.

I'd prefer to do it this way instead of copy-pasting my navbar inside a new error template to avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i had the same issue once, the solution is simple, in the error 404 blade you use `extends('layouts.frontoffice')` right ? then you can pass a variable to this extension, `extends('layouts.frontoffice', ['code' => 404])` and in your navbar component :

```
@if(isset($code) && $code == 404)
//do something
@else
//do something else
@endif
```